# How to filter data with select/dropdown using Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I want to show different different values from JSON data depending on a drop down selection.

```
<div>
    <label for="input-one">select</label>
</div>
<div>
    <select>
        <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
        <option value="1">option1</option>
        <option value="2">option2</option>
        <option value="3">option3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

This is the drop down selection. What is the best approach to show the JSON data based on a selection?

For example:

- If you select `1`, it should show 2 values from JSON data.
- If you select `2`, it should show 3 values from JSON data.
- If you select `3`, it should show all JSON data.

I want to do this in **Angular 2**. Please suggest me what could be the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hello_ Sakura chan :)

I'm not sure that I fully understand your question, but I did understand that you want to show items filtered by `<select>`. If this is the case I can suggest you to use:

- [Event binding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/user-input.html#!#binding-to-user-input-events)
- [Custom Pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#custom-pipes)

**Shortly about Event Binding** ********************************

Basically with *Event binding* you are handling element event like this:

```
<select (change)="onMySelectChange($event)"></select>
```

Now inside **onMySelectChange** you can filter your collection depending on the value of the `<select>`

**Shortly about Custom Pipe** ********************************

Here you make your filter in external file for example - **myfilter.ts**
and then you need to implement interface [PipeTransform](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/PipeTransform-interface.html) with the function `transform(value: any, ...args: any[]) : any`.

Sample pipe would look like:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'myfilter'
})
export class MyFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], filter: Object): any {

        if(filter == 1){
          return items.slice(0, 2);
        }else if(filter == 2){
          return items.slice(0, 3);
        }else if(filter == 3){
          return items;
        }else{
          return [];
        }
    }
}
```

and sample usage would be:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let d of pipeFilterData | myfilter: 2">{{d.value}}</li>
</ul>
```

Don't forget to put your pipe in **declarations** of your app module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App, MyFilterPipe ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
```

[**CLICK HERE TO DIG INTO DEMO CODE**](https://plnkr.co/edit/kNoZmsPkLsK3ijWkkE3R?p=preview)

Comment: Hi @codtex , Awesome..That's the exactly solution I wanted.Thank you so much..:)